# Use of Gauss-Green identity

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

In a solution of the problem 'what is the $C^1$ curve in $\mathbb R^2$, parametrized by arc length, whose inside area is maximum' my professor said that the area could be calculated as $\int_0^{2\pi} x y' dt$ where $x(t),y(t)$ is the parametrisation of the curve. This, he said, by Gauss-Green identity.

The statement I know is $\int_{\Omega} \Delta u\ v+\int_\Omega \nabla u\cdot\nabla v =\int_{\partial \Omega}v\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}$. How can one relate this statement to the above result? (I think one should take $u=x$, $v=y$, but I don't see how this leads to the end, although it is the intuitive way, and, also, the problem seems in fact very easy).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that that integral for area comes from Green's theorem, since the exterior derivative of $x\,dy$ is $1$, and so that integral is equivalent to integrating $1$ over the area. Perhaps he misspoke.

Comment: Oh, very good: it makes perfectly sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that Green's Theorem states that if $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are continuously differentiable in a region $S$ bounded by the positively oriented, piecewise smooth, and simple closed curve in the plane, then

$$\iint_S \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)\,dS=\oint_C (u\,dx+v\,dy) \tag 1$$

Now, letting $u=0$ and $v=x$ in $(1)$, and parameterizing $C$ as $x=x(t)$, $y=y(t)$, yields

$$\iint_S (1)\,dS=\oint_C x(t)\frac{dy(t)}{dt}\,dt$$

as was to be shown!